# declare Array adapter in the non-activity class to use in the fragment

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-dialogfragment

So here is my problem. I'm using a dialog fragment to display some info. In that fragment, i have a spinner view that is filled up by the Array list. Normally I create that adapter in my fragment like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> teamsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),  
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Variables.teamNames); 

teamsAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       Variables.spinner.setAdapter(teamsAdapter);
```

Variables is my user-defined class where I keep all variables.
Now here is my question. I have around 10 DialogFragments and almost all of them have spinner. I would like to define that Adapter in my Variables class and whenever i need it, i would just call it from my variables class. Unfortunately to do that, i need getActivity() in my adapter constructor. I cannot go around it.

BTW, is it a good idea or I should use interface?
It would be awesome if somebody could actually tell me why would I use java interface in android?

Comment: If your questions is answered, I would appreciate if you could mark my answer as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fragment would still need to call some Variables method to retrieve the spinner and to add it to your layout, right? So when you do that call, you can pass the Activity as Context, something like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> teamsAdapter = Variables.getAdapterForTeams(getActivity());
```

The question about the Interface isn't an Android but a Java question. If it makes sense to use an Interface in Java it will make sense to use it in Android. There's plenty of literature and online resources about Java that will explain the why and when Interfaces should be used. I'm sure if you search online you'll find plenty of resources about it.